# Define the value property in ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I am fetching names and respective emails of users from backend through different arrays using loadApprovers() function. I want to submit the user email to backend when i select the user name. I am using ng-options in select element.

**html:**

```
<div class="groups list list-insert" ng-init='request.loadApprover()'>
      <label for="approver1_name" class="item item-input">
      <select  ng-options="item as item.approver1_name for item in request.approver1_email track by item.id"  ng-model="request.approvalObject.approver1_email" ></select>
```

**Controller:**

```
constructor($http, $scope, socket) {

    this.$http = $http;
    console.log("testentry");
    this.approver1_email=[];
    this.approver1_name=[];

}

loadApprover($http, approver1_email, approver1_name) {
    this.$http.get('/api/approvals', approver1_email, approver1_name)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.data)
      this.approver1_email=data.data;

    })
}
```

I cannot submit user email when I select user name. I am a beginner in AngularJS and I cannot get any more ideas how to code ng-options other than this. Can someone guide me how can I write better code to get this task done?

Comment: If you just want the email property of the selected object, you can do `ng-options="item.email as item.approver1_name..."`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to submit the user email to backend when i select the user
>   name.

If you want to do this every time you select the username, try using `ngChange`: [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

It would look something like this...

HTML:

```
<div class="groups list list-insert" ng-init='request.loadApprover()'>
      <label for="approver1_name" class="item item-input">
      <select ng-change="changed(item)"  ng-options="item as item.approver1_name for item in request.approver1_email track by item.id"  ng-model="request.approvalObject.approver1_email" ></select>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.changed = function(item) {
      //logic goes here (item.email is probably the person's email)
    }
```

Example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/o18U4GiCAQHYY2JivUtN)